# Subtract dates for the same serial number in Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, subtraction

Hi I need an SQL code for subtracting dates for MsAccess

For instance

```
serialNumber    serviceWoNumber createdDate type    Results should be
900017672280000 1700028713      17.01.2017   CD 
731127155164500 1600729135      14.12.2016   CD     =14.12.2016-7.12.2016=7
731127155164500 1600712441      7.12.2016    CD     =7.12.2016-5.12.2016=2
```

Thank you very much for any help.

Comment: Where do you find 5.12.2016? How to decide which dates to subtract?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing we are missing some data in the question, but I think I understand your question.

You have a table containing records using the above setup you described (serialNumber, serviceNumber, createdDate, and Type). You want to check how long since the last date an item has been serviced.

You will need to perform some form of a self-join of the table, and then find the use `DATEDIFF` to perform the calculation. It'd look something like the following (pseudo-code):

```
SELECT
    a.serialNumber, DATEDIFF('d', a.createdDate, b.createdDate) AS serviceInterval
FROM
    myTable a
    LEFT JOIN myTable b ON a.serialNumber = b.serialNumber 
    AND a.createdDate > b.createdDate
```

You perform the self-join on the serial number, and the component in a being serviced later in the dataset aliased as a than in b.

This does not take into account items you never serviced before, so probably you need to add some data to deal with `NULL` values in dataset b.

Let me know if I totally misunderstood your issue.

**** Update following comment ****

Following your comment that you'd like to add the subtractionresults, you could use something like the following (Assuming you added a column called serviceInterval:

```
UPDATE myTable updateMe
SET 
    updateMe.serviceInterval = a.serviceInterval
FROM
    myTable a
    LEFT JOIN myTable b ON a.serialNumber = b.serialNumber 
    AND a.createdDate > b.createdDate
WHERE
    updateMe.serialNumber = a.serialNumber
```

Comment: Hi Schmitz IT, 

Thank you very much for your substantial help.
There are many same serial numbers in the warehouse and ı would like to add to an extra column about the subtraction results of each record consecutively depending on date order.

Comment: Hi Schmitz IT, 

Thank you very much for your substantial help.
There are many same serial numbers in the warehouse and ı would like to add to an extra column about the subtraction results of each record consecutively depending on date order.

Should I crate "a" named and "b" named table.

Comment: I took a message that "Enter Parameter Value" for serial number

Comment: Dear @SchmitzIT could you share with me a sample database for this. I have struggled ..looking forward to hearing from you soon. and Thank you very much

Comment: @Sero - As mentioned, it's pretty much pseudo code. I don't really have an Access database available. What did you try, and what was the result?

Comment: Dear @SchmitzIT There are many problems about it. Could you say me should I creat a and b table? You defined myTable a is that means should I create a table named "a"

Comment: @Sero Those are just aliases. The name of the table in the above code is `mytable`

Comment: Dear @SchmitzIT  I added SELECT serialNumber, DATEDIFF('d',a.createdDate,b.createdDate) AS serviceInterval
FROM myTable AS a LEFT JOIN myTable AS b ON (a.serialNumber = b.serialNumber) AND (a.createdDate > b.createdDate); code but I took a message that "The specified field  serialNumber could refer to more than one table listed in the FROM  clause of your SQL Statement"

Comment: @Sero You will need to specify which of the two copies of the table the SerialNumber needs to come from. I.e. `SELECT a.serialNumer, DATEDIFF('d',a.createdDate,b.createdDate) AS serviceInterval FROM myTable AS a LEFT JOIN myTable AS b ON (a.serialNumber = b.serialNumber) AND (a.createdDate > b.createdDate);`. I updated my answer accordingly. I hope that helps :)

Comment: @Sero - Happy to hear it :)

Comment: :) Thank you. I create 2 quarry to handle this
first quarry:Reindexing_CD_FD
SELECT CD_FD.*, (select count(*)  from CD_FD as t2 where t2.SerialNo = CD_FD.SerialNo and t2.ReceivedDate <=CD_FD.ReceivedDate) AS IDK FROM CD_FD ORDER BY CD_FD.SerialNo And CD_FD.ReceivedDate;
2nd:difference date
SELECT T2.SerialNo, T2.SerWorkNumber, T2.ServiceCenter, T2.Type, T2.[ReceivedDate], T1.[ReceivedDate]-T2.[ReceivedDate] AS ['Difference']
FROM Reindexing_CD_FD AS T1 RIGHT JOIN Reindexing_CD_FD AS T2 ON (T1.SerialNo = T2.SerialNo) AND (T1.IDK - T2.IDK =1)
ORDER BY T1.SerialNo, T2.[ReceivedDate] DESC;

Comment: Thank you for all of your substantial effort my code and way looks not professional but that is the my level:)

Comment: @Sero - You're welcome. Could you mark my answer as the answer to your question? That way future visitors can see the proper solution. Thanks :)

Comment: Ok I did it @SchmitzIT